# Parallel Batteries

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[image]

According to Kirchoff Voltage Law we have:
$$ V1-IR1-IR2-V2=0 \implies I=\frac{V1-V2}{R}$$
but when testing this i found a 9V battery connected in parallel with a 1.5 Volt battery gives only 2V https://youtu.be/XoLzn49IZjM. I was wondering why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your diagram, $V$ is calculated as,
$$V=V1-IR1=V1-(\frac{V1-V2}{R1+R2}).R1=\frac{V1R2+V2R1}{R1+R2}$$
or,
$$V=V2+IR2=V2+(\frac{V1-V2}{R1+R2}).R2=\frac{V1R2+V2R1}{R1+R2}$$
$V$ depends upon the resistance you are using, it's not just plain $V1-V2$

Comment: so you use kirchoffs law a second time with V as the voltage variable to get the voltage

Comment: This is wired wrong: the 9V battery is driving the 1.5 volt battery backwards. This will ruin the 1.5 volt battery and run the 9V battery down. You must reverse one set of battery terminals so the - terminal of one is facing the + terminal of the other.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Yes, this combination is not good for the 1.5V battery. But even after this, you can get some current flow in the circuit which can be calculated by Kirchhoff's law. No real-world system can have such a system or at least I can't think of any.

Comment: The voltage of the 1.5 Volt battery increased (even though it was non rechargeable) the voltage of the 9 volt decreased after the experiment. Also the 9 V was much hotter than the 1.5 Volt

Comment: @ChemEng No, it isn't. If you place a voltmeter across the battery without the resistance, unlike the diagram shown, it should still give you 1.5V. 9V battery is hotter because only that is being discharged.